# Runing mix new app_first failed in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create Elixir project using mix taking instructuions from the book "Introducing Exilir" on Windows 7 machine.
After installing latest 64-bit version of Erlang from 
[here](http://www.erlang.org/downloads) and downloding elixir from [there](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases) (Precompiled.zip), I'e added PATH to both elr10.3/bin and elexir/bin folders.
After running cmd and typing

```
mix new first_app
```

I've faced with the crush:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},
{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1115
}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,823}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{_}
,{_}]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Unfortunatelly, there is now unhappy path in the book.

Maybe, somebody here could tell me what to do to make it work in happy path?

Comment: Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: Actually, it is all I've got https://youtu.be/o2cwPbrYDX0. I have erl_crush.dump as well, but it is about 19K lines and I don't know how to post something big like that here.

Comment: The error message that causes this is already there: `{undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[{_},{_}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{_}
,{_}]}]}`. The `undef` error means that either the function `:elixir.start_cli/0` is undefined, or - more likely - that the `:elixir` module wasn't found.